# Google Places Changing Auto-complete Hint & Result Language?

Tags: google-places-api

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

I have a similar page with above google places demo. Notice that the location input field has a hint of "Enter a location". How do i change the language of this hint?
And how do i change the language of the results return?
I guess both of them goes to the same setting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport):

> *"The API detects the browser settings of the user and set the language appropriately. It is possible to override the language in the
>   APIs."*

The input field placeholder will change automatically depending on the users browser agent language setting.

You can also override the automatic language detection by setting the `language` parameter in your bootstrap request to a [supported language](https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1).

E.G.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=ja"></script>
```