# How to change the language of the Google Places Autocomplete results?

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

Is it possible to change the result language of the Google Places Autocomplete iOS component (similar to [changing it when using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307199/google-places-changing-auto-complete-hint-result-language) but in Swift)? Specifically I would like to change the search results language.
Per default it seems to be set to the phone's system language meaning that on my German phone I get German city names and on my English phone I get English ones.
[EDIT]: I'm using the [Google Placepicker](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) Library that can be installed via Cocoa Pods. My code looks very similar to the first code snippet on the linked page.

Comment: As the accepted answer there shows you that you should supply `language` in the request. You can probably get that from the `Locale.current.languageCode`. The details of how one would incorporate that in the request depends a bit upon how you built the request.

Comment: @Rob The question I linked was about JavaScript but I'm looking for a way to change the language in Swift. O:-)

Comment: Yes, I know, but (a) the idea is the same, namely you have to make sure `language` is set; and (b) we can't tell you how to alter your request accordingly if you don't show us how you're currently building the request in Swift.

Comment: @Rob I already searched the documentation for a language option and didn't find one. But you're right I should have included more info about my setup, adding it now.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Kira I'm afraid no, sorry. We found a way around the problem in our project.

Comment: I changed locale for my app to English so now it works but that will be an issue if I ever need localization.

Comment: @Kira Ah, that's smart but you're right, this remains a problem ...

Comment: Here is a workaround of this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246471/can-i-change-the-result-language-of-google-places-api-for-ios/56371056#56371056